# Django Celery Queue getting stuck

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, supervisord

I use Celery/RabbitMQ for asynchronous task execution with my django application. I have just started working with Celery.

The tasks execute and everything works perfectly once I start the worker.

The Problem is that the tasks execution stops sometime later. After couple of hours, a day or sometimes couple of days. I realise that only from the consequences of incomplete task executions. Then I restart celery and all the pending tasks get executed and everything is back to normal.

My questions are:

- How can I debug (where to start looking) to find out what the problem is?
- How can I create a mechanism that shall notify me immediately after the problem starts?

My Stack:
Django 1.4.8
Celery 3.1.16
RabbitMQ
Supervisord

Thanks,
andy

Comment: Have you tried RabbitMQ management plugin and see if there any issues with RabbitMQ queues at the time of stuck? That way you will be one step close that issue is not in RabbitMQ and in Celery(May be)?

Comment: @nIKUNJ will try to do that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Celery worker hangs without any error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30272845/celery-worker-hangs-without-any-error)

Answer (score 10):

(1) If your celery worker get stuck sometimes, you can use `strace & lsof` to find out at which system call it get stuck.

For example:

```
$ strace -p 10268 -s 10000
Process 10268 attached - interrupt to quit
recvfrom(5,
```

10268 is the pid of celery worker, `recvfrom(5` means the worker stops at receiving data from file descriptor.

Then you can use `lsof` to check out what is `5` in this worker process.

```
lsof -p 10268
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE    DEVICE SIZE/OFF      NODE NAME
......
celery  10268 root    5u  IPv4 828871825      0t0       TCP 172.16.201.40:36162->10.13.244.205:wap-wsp (ESTABLISHED)
......
```

It indicates that the worker get stuck at a tcp connection(you can see `5u` in `FD` column).

Some python packages like `requests` is blocking to wait data from peer, this may cause celery worker hangs, if you are using `requests`, please make sure to set `timeout` argument.

(2)you can monitor your celery task queue size in RabbitMQ, if it keep increasing in a long time, probably celery worker is going on strike.

---

Have you seen this page:

https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2013/10/30/using-strace-debug-stuck-celery-tasks/

Comment: Mate, I owe you a beer for this.  We've been stuck on this exact issue for 2 months, having to respawn all of our AWS servers every 4-5 days or so, because we weren't using `timeout` in requests.  Thanks!