# Celery worker hangs without any error

Tags: python, celery, blocking, gevent

I have a production setup for running celery workers for making a POST / GET request to remote service and storing result, It is handling load around 20k tasks per 15 min.

The problem is that the workers go numb for no reason, no errors, no warnings.

I have tried adding multiprocessing also, the same result.

In log I see the increase in the time of executing task, like succeeded in s

For more details look at https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2621

Comment: Is "Storing the response in MongoDB"  part asynchronous? Have logs for that?

Answer (score 41):

If your celery worker get stuck sometimes, you can use `strace & lsof` to find out at which system call it get stuck.

For example:

```
$ strace -p 10268 -s 10000
Process 10268 attached - interrupt to quit
recvfrom(5,
```

10268 is the pid of celery worker, `recvfrom(5` means the worker stops at receiving data from file descriptor.

Then you can use `lsof` to check out what is `5` in this worker process.

```
lsof -p 10268
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE    DEVICE SIZE/OFF      NODE NAME
......
celery  10268 root    5u  IPv4 828871825      0t0       TCP 172.16.201.40:36162->10.13.244.205:wap-wsp (ESTABLISHED)
......
```

It indicates that the worker get stuck at a tcp connection(you can see `5u` in `FD` column).

Some python packages like `requests` is blocking to wait data from peer, this may cause celery worker hangs, if you are using `requests`, please make sure to set `timeout` argument.

---

Have you seen this page:

https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2013/10/30/using-strace-debug-stuck-celery-tasks/

Answer (score 5):

> I also faced the issue, when I was using delay shared_task with
> celery, kombu, amqp, billiard. After calling the API when I used
> delay() for @shared_task, all functions well but when it goes to delay
> it hangs up.
>
> So, the issue was In main Application **init**.py, the below settings
> were missing
>
> ## This will make sure the app is always imported when  # Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.

In **init**.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celeryApp

#__all__ = ('celeryApp',)
__all__ = ['celeryApp']
```

> ## Note1: In place of celery_app put the Aplication name, means the Application mentioned in celery.py import the App and put here
>
> ## Note2:** If facing only hangs issue in shared task above solution may solve your issue and ignore below matters.
>
> Also wanna mention A=another issue, If anyone facing Error 111
> connection issue then please check the versions of amqp==2.2.2,
> billiard==3.5.0.3, celery==4.1.0, kombu==4.1.0 whether they are
> supporting or not. Mentioned versions are just an example. And Also
> check whether redis is install in your system(If any any using redis).
>
> Also make sure you are using Kombu 4.1.0. In the latest version of
> Kombu renames async to asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr You should increase rabbitmq free disk space above configured limit (`disk_free_limit`).

---

Another case: RabbitMq is in lack of disk free space:
[image]

From RabbitMq [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/disk-alarms.html#overview):

> When free disk space drops below a configured limit (50 MB by default), an alarm will be triggered and all producers will be blocked.

Related Celery [topic](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1312) for more info.

In my case celery hung on `recv` function:

```
File "/app/manage.py", line 32, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 398, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in populate
    app_config.ready()
File "/app/my_app/api_v1/apps.py", line 21, in ready
    process_data.delay()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 444, in delay
    return self.apply_async(args, kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/celery.py", line 129, in apply_async
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 594, in apply_async
    return app.send_task(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 798, in send_task
    amqp.send_task_message(P, name, message, **options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py", line 554, in send_task_message
    evd.publish('task-sent', sent_event,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/events/dispatcher.py", line 139, in publish
    return self._publish(event, producer,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/events/dispatcher.py", line 146, in _publish
    producer.publish(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 186, in publish
    return _publish(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 563, in _ensured
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 202, in _publish
    [maybe_declare(entity) for entity in declare]
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 202, in <listcomp>
    [maybe_declare(entity) for entity in declare]
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 107, in maybe_declare
    return maybe_declare(entity, self.channel, retry, **retry_policy)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/common.py", line 113, in maybe_declare
    return _maybe_declare(entity, channel)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/common.py", line 153, in _maybe_declare
    entity.declare(channel=channel)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/entity.py", line 184, in declare
    return (channel or self.channel).exchange_declare(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/amqp/channel.py", line 624, in exchange_declare
    self.send_method(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/amqp/abstract_channel.py", line 79, in send_method
    return self.wait(wait, returns_tuple=returns_tuple)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/amqp/abstract_channel.py", line 99, in wait
    self.connection.drain_events(timeout=timeout)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 525, in drain_events
    while not self.blocking_read(timeout):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 530, in blocking_read
    frame = self.transport.read_frame()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 294, in read_frame
    frame_header = read(7, True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 627, in _read
    s = recv(n - len(rbuf))
```

Answer (score -6):

Follow this tutorial

[Celery Django Link](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html)

Add the following to the settings

> NB Install redis for both transport and result

```
   # TRANSPORT
   CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT = 'redis'
   CELERY_BROKER_HOST = 'localhost'
   CELERY_BROKER_PORT = '6379'
   CELERY_BROKER_VHOST = '0'

   # RESULT
   CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis'
   CELERY_REDIS_HOST = 'localhost'
   CELERY_REDIS_PORT = '6379'
   CELERY_REDIS_DB = '1'
```